# How to get exact value using contain jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table as below

```
ID Name
1  David
11 John
```

I want to get the row has id = 1:

```
var row1 = $(this).closest("tr").nextAll("tr").has("td:eq(0):contains(1)");
```

but the output returned two rows. How do I get the exact value?

Comment: by `id`, I assume you don't really mean the html element id?

Comment: What does your table's markup look like? What is `this` in the context of your script?

Comment: tldr: (for duplicate,) use .filter with a custom method that returns true or false based on whether or not the tr should be returned. The id you are filtering by should probably be a data attribute on the TR which would make this far easier.

Comment: @ajm: this is a grid.

Comment: @KevinB: I know that can use filter to implement it, but I cannot implement to filter follow td. Please help me.

Comment: yes you can. please explain why you cant?

Comment: @KevinB: I'm implementing as below: var row1 = $(this).closest("tr").nextAll("tr").filter(function() {
                        // To do
                    }); I don't know implement to get the row has id = 1

Comment: Your requirement is that the first cell contain the exact text "1" correct? that's pretty basic with jQuery. http://pastebin.com/KMH4zTP9 Select the first cell of the current row, get it's text, and compare the text to your target id.